# Protobuf-net v2 alpha compile dll problem for iphone

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, protobuf-net, unity-game-engine

We're developing a cross-platform online game using unity3d(monotouch) engine (C#), and we use protobuf-net (thanks to Marc Gravell) as protocol.
As we know, reflection does not work on iOS. It is not allowed by Apple to have code generated dynamically. We checked Marc's blog (http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/), and found the early protobuf-net v2(though it's not completed yet) may avoid reflection problem.

we made some test and try to pre-compile serialize code into dll file, howerver, when we run it on ios , we got the following message.

>

```
     System.IO.FileNotFoundException has been thrown
>     “Could not load file or assembly “DataBuilder , Version=0.0.0.0 , 
> Culture = neutrual , PublicKeyToken =
> null ”” or one of its dependencies.”
```

here is our compile dll code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ProtoBuf;
using ProtoBuf.Meta;
using Data;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bb = TypeModel.Create();
            bb.Add(typeof(Customer), true);
            bb.Compile("DataBuilder", "databuilder.dll");
        }
    }
}
```

here is our test code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Data;
using System.IO;
using ProtoBuf;
using ProtoBuf.Meta;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var creater = new DataBuilder();  // that's it

            var dd = new Data.Customer();
            dd.Name = "Hellow World";
            dd.CustomerId = "1232";
            MemoryStream mm = new MemoryStream();
            creater.Serialize(mm, dd);
            mm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Data.Customer c = (Data.Customer)creater.Deserialize(mm, null, typeof(Data.Customer));
            Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

We compiled dll under Windows enviornment(compact framework .net 3.5), maybe it didn't work on monotouch.

Comment: Since this is pre-release etc, I would suggest it would be more appropriate to use the bug-report; I have moved this here: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=165